# Extracting information form multiple arrays

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell, unix

I am trying to use multiple arrays to extract information from a file and then `echo` that information out.

The question from my homework is:

•   Use the /var/log/messages file, ask the user to enter a service name (eg. “syslogd”) and display the number of times the service restarted for a specific date.
So for instance if the service restarted **5** times on **November 11 2014**, and **3** times on **November 12 2014** your output should resemble the following:

> The syslogd service restarted 5 times on Nov 10, the times are: 22:00:04
>
> The syslogd service restarted 3 times on Nov 11, the times are: 22:00:04

My code is:

```
echo -n "Enter the name of the service you wish to log: "; read input
array1=($(grep $input /var/log/messages | awk '{print $1,$2}' | uniq -c | cut -d ' ' -f 4))
array2=$(grep $input /var/log/messages | awk '{print $1,$2}' | uniq | tr -d " ")

for element in "${array1[@]}"
do
    for elementTwo in "${array2[@]}"
    do
        echo "The "$input" service restarted "$element" times on"$elementTwo" "
    done
done
```

My output is:

```
Enter the name of the service you wish to log: syslogd

The syslogd service restarted 2 times onOct30 Oct31 Nov1 Nov2 Nov3 Nov4 Nov5 Nov6 Nov7 Nov8 Nov9              Nov10 Nov11 Nov12 Nov13 Nov14 Nov15 Nov16 Nov17 Nov18 Nov19 Nov20 Nov21 Nov22 Nov23 Nov24 Nov25 Nov26 Nov27 Nov28 Nov29

The syslogd service restarted 2 times onOct30 Oct31 Nov1 Nov2 Nov3 Nov4 Nov5 Nov6 Nov7 Nov8 Nov9 Nov10 Nov11 Nov12 Nov13 Nov14 Nov15 Nov16 Nov17 Nov18 Nov19 Nov20 Nov21 Nov22 Nov23 Nov24 Nov25 Nov26 Nov27 Nov28 Nov29

The syslogd service restarted 3 times onOct30 Oct31 Nov1 Nov2 Nov3 Nov4 Nov5 Nov6 Nov7 Nov8 Nov9 Nov10 Nov11 Nov12 Nov13 Nov14 Nov15 Nov16 Nov17 Nov18 Nov19 Nov20 Nov21 Nov22 Nov23 Nov24 Nov25 Nov26 Nov27 Nov28 Nov29
```

Output from /var/log/messages:

```
Nov 28 08:00:05 opentech syslogd: restart
Nov 28 22:00:04 opentech syslogd: restart
Nov 29 04:00:05 opentech syslogd: restart
Nov 29 20:00:05 opentech syslogd: restart
Nov 29 22:00:07 opentech syslogd: restart
```

There is more to the output but I think you get the point! As you can see it is outputting all of the dates instead of one per line. I have no idea how to fix this. Please help!!!

Comment: Can you give a few sample lines from `/var/log/messages` ?

Comment: Nov 28 08:00:05 opentech syslogd: restart
Nov 28 22:00:04 opentech syslogd: restart
Nov 29 04:00:05 opentech syslogd: restart
Nov 29 20:00:05 opentech syslogd: restart
Nov 29 22:00:07 opentech syslogd: restart

Comment: `array2` isn't an array.

Comment: Well that would do it. Is there a way to turn it into an array?

Comment: Just put `array2=( $(grep ... ) )` But there seems to be some other problems with your code also.. For example, you only need a single `for` loop, and the `cut -d' ' -f4` is not working.

Comment: See I was thinking I need a single for loop last night but I couldn't figure out how to put the multiple arguments into it. And I will fix the cut command.

Comment: Now that the array works I am trying to combine everything into a single for loop but once again it is not working. How would you put in the multiple variables into the loop? For example would it be something like: 'code for element, elementTwo in "${array1[@]}" "${array2[@]}"
do
 echo "The "$input" service restarted "$element" times on "$elementTwo" "
done'

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Perl script for fun if you are interested:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $service=shift;
my %h;
open (my $fh, "<", '/var/log/messages') or die "Could not open log file: $!\n";
while (<$fh>) {
    if (/$service.*restart/) {
        my($f1,$f2,$f3)=split;
        my $key="$f1 $f2";
        $h{$key}{cnt}++;
        if (exists $h{$key}{arr}) {
            push (@{$h{$key}{arr}}, $f3);
        } else {
            $h{$key}{arr}=[$f3];
        }
    }
}
close($fh);

for (sort keys %h) {
    print "The $service service restarted " . $h{$_}{cnt} . " times on " .
      $_ . ". The times are: " . join (", ", @{$h{$_}{arr}}) . ".\n";
}
```

You run it using:

```
$ script.pl syslogd
```

Output:

```
The syslogd service restarted 2 times on Nov 28. The times are: 08:00:05, 22:00:04.
The syslogd service restarted 3 times on Nov 29. The times are: 04:00:05, 20:00:05, 22:00:07.
```

Comment: I am always interested! Thank you